# How can I get rid of the scientific notation when selecting big number on Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, oracle, scientific-notation

I need to import a big number to another table using queries, but it always shows with scientific notation. It has to be a number because sorting is necessary and it does not work with char.

I tried all kinds of casting, it changes the number of decimal places but still shows as scientific notation.

```
SELECT
    CAST(PO_SID AS decimal(38,0)) AS PO_SID,
FROM CMS.PO_V'

When using 

  to_number(replace(PO_V.PO_SID,' ',''),
    '9.99999999999999999999EEEE'),
```

it outputs:

```
Erro de SQL: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
```

Comment: Can you describe the process you're using  Assuming `po_sid` is defined as numeric in the database, the client is responsible for determining how to display the result.  Different clients will have different settings for how (and whether) to use scientific notation.  You say you're importing data into another table but it's not clear if you're doing a simple `insert into destination select columns from source` or whether you're doing something like using `SQL*Plus` to export a flat file that you're trying to import into a destination.

Comment: I have to import this data on an In-Memory system. But on this system, I have to script on default SQL but the database is in Oracle, so the solution that we came up with was to write the Oracle script as a string and then do:

IMPORT [table] = [source].{@@query}

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand.  When you talk about an "Oracle script", are you talking about a `SQL*Plus` script?  Or are you using some other tool to run SQL statements against Oracle?  If you are using some other tool to run SQL against Oracle, you'd probably want to look at that tool's settings to understand when and where it displays numbers using scientific notation.

Comment: Take a look at the NLS parameters; since the error message you are seeing is apparently in Portuguese, the number's format specification for the decimal point in the `to_number` function may need to be a `,` (comma) instead of a `.` (period).